# angularjs injector not working in mobile browser

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting `[$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: AccountProvider <- Account <- loginCtrol http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.9/$injector/unpr?po=AccountProvider` error only on my mobile phone browser. I do not get this error on tablets and desktop browser. The app has been working as expected on desktop browser (chrome).

I have the following code structure:

```
/app.js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui-router', 'controllers', 'services']);

/services.js
var services= angular.module('services', []);

/controllers.js
var controllers = angular.module('controllers', []);

/services/account.js
services.factory('Account', ['$http', function($http)
{
return {
    Login: function(username, password)
    {
       $http.post('/api/login', {username:username, password:password}).
        then(function(result){   });
    }
}
}]);

/controllers/loginCtrol.js
controllers.controller('loginCtrl', ['Account', '$scope', function(Account, $scope)
{
   $scope.login = function(username, password)
   {
       Account.Login(username, password);
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

you have registered your **Account** service wrong way.

you shoud write :

```
controllers.factory('Account', ['$http', function($http)
{
return {
    Login: function(username, password)
    {
       $http.post('/api/login', {username:username, password:password}).
        then(function(result){   });
    }
}
}]);
```

Comment: that breaks the app even on desktop browser.

Comment: I had to move the files around, so the desktop browser still works, but fails in mobile, same error.

Comment: can you please make your ervice by below way:                                              app.service('Account', [ "$http",function $http) {
    this.Login = function(username, password){
       $http.post('/api/login', {username:username, password:password}).
        then(function(result){   });                                                                          }
}]);

Comment: Also let me know the order of the files which you have written.Thanks

Comment: Still does not work on mobile. Order app.js -> services.js -> controllers.js -> account.js -> loginCtrl.js.
Perhaps the answer below is the reason, I am testing on blackberry 9320.

Answer (score 0):

This problem  is regarding mobile web view, Please update your mobile web view to solve this type of error.If you use old mobile view then definitely getting this type of error.

Thanks